# Have the niceties of extended prototype without actually extending the prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

What I'm trying to do is have an interface where you can wrap an element into an instance which has an extended prototype, so something like.

```js
const wrappedButton = new WrappedElem(document.getElementById('some-button'))
// we have access to our custom added method:
console.log(`I am the ${wrappedButton.siblingIndex()}th button`)

// but we still have access to the original methods
wrappedButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  console.log('I clicked on', e.target)
  // right here we won't have access to siblingIndex, because the prototype of the element itself was not changed.
})
```

I can extend the original prototype like this

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.siblingIndex = function() {
    if(this.parentNode == null) {
        return -1
    }
    
    return Array.prototype.indexOf.call(this.parentNode.children, this)
}
```

But extending the prototype is bad practice, and bad performance.

So it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Why you need to do that in the first place ? you can just define your function somewhere and do `siblingIndex(el)` or even `siblingIndex.call(el)` if you want to keep using this

Comment: Yes, I can understand that you could do it that way, I mean, you could also do `var a = []` and then do `Array.prototype.push.call(a, 23)` every time you wanted to append an item to the array, but doing `a.push(23)` just looks cleaner, and it's also a better syntax, plus by defining a function inside of a specific scope, you make it clear that it's defined under that scope, rather than it being a standalone function.

Comment: Then you will have to use a Proxy guess, that will forward calls to the underlying object, and have an additional method

Comment: And how about [using custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)? Maybe [customized built-in elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#customized_built-in_elements) do already cover the OP's needs/scenario?

Comment: There is absolutely no need to access or set `prototype` in this day and age for DOM manipulation or reads.

I understand it may be desirable from a syntactical POV but boring functions are cheap and easy to maintain. If you want it to be portable wrap it in an object.

I've seen this type of code come and go over a decade, it's results in nothing but a mess.

All you need is:

`const getIndex = el => Array.from(el.parentElement.children).indexOf(el)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a Proxy we can add a new method without protoype changes :

```js
const siblingIndex = () => {}

const handler = {
    get(target, property) {
        
        if(property === 'siblingIndex') {
            return siblingIndex;
        }

        return target[property];
    }
}

const proxyButton = new Proxy(button, handler);

// we can also call the siblingIndex function
proxyButton.siblingIndex();
// we can access the properties of the underlying object
proxyButton.tagName;
```

e.target however will not return the proxy but the original object,
but you can just use proxyButton instead of e.target

if you want you can also override the addEventListener method to return the proxied version instead when the callback is called

Comment: Right, this almost works, I'm just trying to figure out how to get the correct this inside of the function, without using bind.

Comment: i used an arrow function here but a normal function should have a correct this i think ( not 100% sure but worth a rry )

Comment: Edit, this does not work. addEventlistener gives an Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: mm strange perhaps its due to the fact that its a dom element, i would try target[property].bind(target) for functions, perhaps its an issue with this

Comment: Yeah, it's a problem with this.

Comment: Proxy is also a bit slow at times

Answer (score 0):

This is what seems to work alright. Big thanks to Lk77.

```js
var wrappedElMethods = {
    siblingIndex() {
        if(this.parentNode == null) {
            return -1
        }
        
        return Array.prototype.indexOf.call(this.parentNode.children, this)
    }
}

function wrappedEl(el) {
    return proxyInherit(el, wrappedElMethods)
}

function proxyInherit(item, overwrites) {
    const handler = {
        get(target, property) {
            
            let value
            const overwriteVal = overwrites[property]
            
            if(overwriteVal != undefined) {
                value = overwriteVal
            } else {
                value = target[property]
            }
            
            if(value instanceof Function) {
                return value.bind(item)
            }
            
            return value
        },
        set(target, property, value) {
            target[property] = value
        }
    }
    
    return new Proxy(item, handler)
}


// Usage:
var button = wrappedEl(e.target)
button.onclick = function() {
  console.log(button.siblingIndex())
}
```